# Faster Approach of Comparing Two Arrays of Objects with Literal Values In Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, lodash

1. The ***Array of Objects with Literal Values*** means, it's an array, each of its element is a object, while such object's values are all literals (so it won't be nested objects, array inside object, etc.), for example, it can be:

```
[ { name: 'Bob', age: 20, isMale: true }, { name: 'Alice', age: 19, isMale: false}, ... ]
```

2. The ***Compare*** means, we need to differentiate `added` and `removed`elements, for example:

```
const original = [ { name: 'Bob', age: 20, isMale: true }, { name: 'Alice', age: 19, isMale: false} ];
const modified = [ { name: 'Alice', age: 19, isMale: false}, { name: 'Jay', age: 21, isMale: true } ];

// then added = [{ name: 'Jay', age: 21, isMale: true }]
// and removed = [{ name: 'Bob', age: 20, isMale: true }]
```

My approach: using lodash's ***differenceWith*** and ***isEqual*** to make things work, for example:

```
const original = [ { name: 'Bob', age: 20, isMale: true }, { name: 'Alice', age: 19, isMale: false} ];
const modified = [ { name: 'Alice', age: 19, isMale: false}, { name: 'Jay', age: 21, isMale: true } ];

const removed = _.differenceWith(original, modified, _.isEqual);
const added = _.differenceWith(modified, original, _.isEqual);
```

^ However, it's not ***FAST ENOUGH***!!
I have a sample of two arrays, each array contains 10K+ objects while each object has 3 properties with lietal values. like this:

```
[{lat: 123.321, long: 234.432, radius: 100}, ....]         // 10K+ elements
```

I tested by myself, using my approach will cost:

1. ~10 seconds to complete <= too slow
2. the browser will freeze due to heavy computation <= the major problem!

Now, the question is, can you provide a much faster and more elegant way to ***Compare*** such samples?

One of my guess is I can improve by replacing the `isEqual` to something else, but not sure if it helps in such situation.

Comment: you mention the browser freezing....are you doing this asychronously?  won't help performance...but prevents as freeze at least id think

Comment: Your data structure is the fundamental problem. Comparing the two arrays will be an O(n^2) operation.

Comment: Maybe instead of arrays you could use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for that?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thanks, will test by using async funcs

Comment: @Pointy
Yeah, I think the only part can be improved is just inner object comparison.

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro
No, we can't. It fundamentally changed the compared data, it should be avoid since you changed the data amount, of course it will compute faster, but this hacky way won't solve the problem theoretically, for example, all 10K+ elements are distinct, so array or set won't make difference :)

Comment: @Meow lookups in an array are always `O(n)` while lookups in a Set are always sub-linear. Depends on the implementation but a Set would always be faster, some provide `O(1)` access but others do `O(log(n))`

Comment: @VLAZ
Indeed, but it's trade off, using Set make things faster but it missed some cases for example array allowed `duplicated` items which also need to be tracked in this problem, just like below answer you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

Comparing each object with each object will lead to `O(n^2)` issue, which as you noticed is complexity that is growing pretty fast and then 10k objects (which is not much in computer world) are almost unprocessable.

There is however easier way how to go through this.

Preprocessing

1. Sort both arrays by name, this takes `O(n*log(n))`
2. Have two indexes to each array starting at `0`, lets call it `i` and `j`

Handling

1. Compare names in `original[i]` and `modified[j]`
2. If it is same, just `i++` and `j++`
3. If it differs, then check which one is "lower" in string comparision (Like Bob is lower than Cathrine because it starts with `B`)
4. If the `original[i]` is lower, add it to `removed` and `i++`
5. If the `modified[j]` is lower, add it to `added` and `j++`
6. Repeat until you process both arrays

The most expensive part is the sorting, everything else is done in `O(n)` time, therefore overall complexity will be `O(n*log(n))` which is good enough even for millions of items.

Note: If you need also compare i.e. age or gender, not just names, you need to update the above with sorting by multiple fields and then comparing by multiple fields)